# How delete image upload after run test using medialibrary spatie?

Tags: laravel, tdd

I have created a test to be able to create a Banner which includes a name, description, order, activate and an image, I am using the spatie medialibrary library.

The test passes correctly but the problem I see is that I saved the image in the assigned folder and it doesn't get deleted, when the test is finished.
How can I tell medialibrary not to save the image or delete it.

[image: Test]

[image: Test banner]

[image: Browse]

Comment: Did you try Storage::fake('public'); before uploading images for testing purpose

Comment: @SachinKumar see my image, before send post, I'm uses Storage::fake('public')

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but in case somebody else is looking for an answer:

Running `Storage::fake('public');`  again at the end of your test function should delete all the files created during your test.

```
public function test_a_banner_can_be_created_as_a_superadmin()
{
    $user = User::find();
    $this->actingAs($user);

    Storage::fake('public');

    $this->post(route('banners.store', [
        'name' => 'Banner home',
        'description' => 'Banner',
        'sort' => 1,
        'active' => 1,
        'image' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('banner-fake.jpg', 600, 300)
    ]));

    $this->assertCount(1, Banner::all());

    Storage::fake('public'); // <-- RUN AGAIN TO DELETE 'banner-fake.jpg'    
}
```